# Canon body names in tags

Tags: discussion, tag-naming

Canon market their entry level DSLR bodies with different names in different markets. For example, in Europe they have the EOS 550D, in North America it is called the EOS Rebel T2i and  in Japan it is the EOS Kiss X4. (See [this question for a full list](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2146/translating-canon-dslr-body-codenames).)

Obviously we should use [tag synonyms](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/tag-folksonomy-and-tag-synonyms/) to make them equivalent, but which should be the canonical name?

Comment: Good question! I myself would go for model number, since that seems to be more ubiquitous than the rest.

Answer (score 6):

Based purely on the fact that [wikipedia use 550D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_EOS_550D) as the title of their article, I'd say the number only one should be the canonical reference, so `[canon-550d]` (I think the eos bit is redundant for the tag.)

Any other reasons?

(I'm answering my question so the rest of you can vote on whether you like this).

Comment: I would choose this, for a few reasons. For one, I think the base model numbers are more common, and used in comparisons between brands more often. Second, its simple, vs. trying to have a tag that uses every term such as canon-550D-rebel-t2i...thats just verbose and too complex. Finally, this is even assuming we DO tag threads with model numbers. See http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/25/should-we-tag-by-model-number for a previous discussion, the outcome of which was generally: don't tag with model numbers, just tab with brands and series.

Comment: It seems that there have been other discussions about tagging with model numbers, and some clearer information about how to search with tags. It sounds like we might start tagging threads as specifically as possible, in which case, this option is very intriguing.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the fact that there are more English speakers in North America than Europe, we should use the American names - `[canon-t2i]`. (I think the Rebel part is redundant).

Any other reasons?

(I'm answering my question so the rest of you can vote on whether you like this).

Answer (score -1):

To keep everyone happy, the canonical tag should have both the European and North American names, so for the 550D the tag should be `[canon-550D-t2i]`

Note I'm rejecting `[eos-550D-t2i]`, `[canon-550D-rebel-t2i]` and anything involving the Kiss names used in Japan.